# Class App/Http/Controllers/View Not Found error

Tags: laravel-5

I am new to laravel 5 and currently stumped by this error:

```
FatalErrorException in TicketController.php line 18: Class 'App\Http\Controllers\View' not found
```

Weird thing is the view does in fact exist, i checked to see if the route was indeed routing to the right controller and it was, the error pops up when i try to do this:

```
return View::make('tickets.bus.index');
```

It's either i am making some mistake somewhere or if the implementation is different from laravel 4

Answer (score 98, accepted):

The problem is not the actual view but the **class** `View`. You see when you just reference a class like `View::make('tickets.bus.index')` PHP searches for the class in your **current namespace**.

In this case that's `App\Http\Controllers`. However the `View` class obviously doesn't exists in your namespace for controllers but rather in the Laravel framework namespace. It has also an alias that's in the *global* namespace.

You can either reference the alias in the root namespace by prepending a backslash:

```
return \View::make('tickets.bus.index');
```

Or add an import statement at the top:

```
use View;
```

Comment: @lukeasgeiter, would you prefer to use  `/View::make()` in the controller method or the `use View` declaration?

Comment: @musicliftsme Definitely `use View`. Or maybe even the `view()` helper function.

Answer (score 25):

In Laravel 5.1 the correct `use` code would be:

`use Illuminate\Support\Facades\View;`

Comment: Thanks, I have solved problem.
Would you please do me a favor?
I have js and css files in resource directive(resource dir that consist asset, views,land dirs).
I need to load js and css files from views/index.html.
Please help me.

Comment: try this in laravel 6.2 and its worked for me, thanks alot

Answer (score 9):

There exists a helper-function, `view()`, which is in the global namespace, and may be used to simplify the syntax:

`return view('tickets.bus.index');`

With this method, it is unnecessary to include `use View;` or include the root namespace, e.g., `\View`.

The concepts that lukasgeiter explained are essential to understanding Laravel, even if you elect to use the helper-function.

Answer (score 2):

For me it was namespace problem. I used php artisan to create controller but it seems like php artisan used different namespace (may be I have to change something in composer.json to fix it but I am totally new in laravel)

`Whoops, looks like something went wrong.
FatalErrorException in PagesController.php line 11:
Class 'App\Http\Controllers\Controller' not found`

Good that I am using phpStorm which automatically inserted proper namespace

**make sure you check out namespace properly. This is how I had controller created with php artisan**

```
    namespace App\Http\Controllers;
    use App\Http\Requests;
    use App\Http\Controllers\Controller; //php artisan inserted.
    class PagesController extends Controller
    {
        public function index(){
            return view('index');
        }
        public function about(){
            return view('pages.about');
        }
    }
```

**and this is how phpstorm inserted after I manually wrote extends controller**

```
    namespace App\Http\Controllers;
    use App\Http\Requests;
    use Illuminate\Routing\Controller; //I manually wrote extends Controller and selected this namespace 

    class PagesController extends Controller
    {
        public function index(){

     ...
```

Answer (score 0):

There exists a helper-function, view(), which is in the global namespace, and may be used to simplify the syntax:

return view('tickets.bus.index');

```
With this method, it is unnecessary to include use View; or include the root namespace, e.g., \View.
```

The concepts that lukasgeiter explained are essential to understanding Laravel, even if you elect to use the helper-function.