# Get a UserID in Laravel 5.0

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I use the baked in Auth in Laravel 5.0, which is such a head-start. What I can't figure out is how to query the database with an authenticated User's ID.

E.g. "Get all the posts for User ID 1".

From the User.php model, I can see the following function:

```
getId();
```

but,

```
$userid = getId();
```

doesn't work.

How would I define or grab the userID so that I can query my database on user-based variables?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From a controller, you can use `Auth::user()` to get the logged in user, and `Auth::user()->id` to get the logged in user's id.

Also note that you can use `Auth::id()` as a shortcut for `Auth::user()->id`

Additionally, there are two other methods you could use (from the `$request` instance and via a function type-hint).  You can read about them in the laravel [docs](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/authentication#retrieving-the-authenticated-user).

For your particular question, you could define the `$userid` as follows: `$userid = \Auth::id();`

Comment: Thanks! I get this error: "Class 'Namespace\Http\Controllers\Auth' not found". Should I include use\namespace\user; in my controller?

Comment: If you manually generated the controller you need to import the proper namespace with `use Illuminate\Routing\Controller;`.  However, you should really look into generating the controllers with artisan (`php artisan make:controller PhotoController`).  You can read more about it [here](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/controllers#restful-resource-controllers).

Comment: @matt You have to reference it using a backslash `\Auth::user()` or add an import statement `user Auth;` at the top. Also note that you can use `Auth::id()` as a shortcut for `Auth::user()->id`

Comment: @lukasgeiter thank you so much! Great contribution. I didn't realize about the backslash - is that because it's built into Laravel 5.0?

Comment: Take a look at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28931738/1903366) it's about the `View` class but the principle is the same.